fill @value variable in a test
I want to test this KeyStoreConfig class but what ends up happening is jceksFileLocation is always null and returns an error What can I do to test this class thoroughly. If I could somwhow populate jceksFileLocation variable I believe I can acheive the desired result.
 @Configuration
    public class KeyStoreConfig {
    
        @Value("${path}")
        private String jceksFileLocation;
        private Environment environment;
    
        public KeyStoreConfig(Environment environment) {
            this.environment = environment;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public KeyStoreKeySelectorFactory keySelectorFactory() {
    
            return new KeyStoreKeySelectorFactory(
                    getClass().getResourceAsStream(jceksFileLocation),
                    "JCEKS",
                    environment.getProperty("keystore.password"));
        }
    }


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "oauth2.keystore.path=/misc/oauth-keys-dev.jceks" })
class KeyStoreConfigTest {

    KeyStoreConfig keyStoreConfig;
    Environment environment;
    KeyStoreKeySelectorFactory keySelectorFactory;

    @BeforeEach
    void init(){
        environment = Mockito.mock(Environment.class);
        keyStoreConfig= new KeyStoreConfig(environment);
    }

    KeyStoreKeySelectorFactory keySelectorFactory(){
        Assertions.assertNotNull(keyStoreConfig.keySelectorFactory());
    }
}


ReflectionTestUtils.setField(keyStoreConfig, "jceksFileLocation", "");

You have a different property name in your Configuration bean than the one in your test TestPropertySource, path vs cima.oauth2.keystore.path
Other than that, your code appears correct, even though it is unclear why you use both @Value and Environment
@Value("${path}")
private String jceksFileLocation;

@TestPropertySource(properties = { "cima.oauth2.keystore.path=/misc/oauth-keys-dev.jceks" })

